# Usage of hain't

Tags: slang, dialects, word-usage

According to Dictionary.com, [ain't](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ain%27t?s=t) has two meanings:

> 1. *Nonstandard except in some dialects.* am not; are not; is not.
> 2. *Nonstandard.* have not; has not; do not; does not; did not.

When I lived in the southern part of the US, I also heard [hain't](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hain%27t) with some frequency as well.

Dictionary.com has this definition:

> *Nonstandard Older Use.* ain't; have not; has not.

From this, it seems like *hain't* and *ain't* are possibly interchangeable, but because *hain't* includes specifically *have not* and *has not* in this definition, I wonder if the usage of *hain't* is restricted to these senses of *ain't*.

If that's the case, then I would expect that

> I hain't ever satisfied.*

would sound wrong in these dialects, but

> I hain't ever been satisfied.

would be the correct expression. Can anyone confirm that this is the case?  Also, are *hain't* and *ain't* used in the same dialects, or is *hain't*'s usage more regionally restricted than *ain't*?

Comment: Never heard of it in the UK. Not even in badly-researched Victorian period drama. It might still be *slightly* more "sloppy" to use *ain't* for *has not, have not / hasn't haven't*, as well as *isn't, aren't*. But putting the "h" in sounds almost like [Cockney/Mockney overcorrection](http://www.englishforums.com/English/HowPronounceNewspaperCommentary/2/kdggx/post.htm) to me.

Comment: But I'm not clear on exactly what you're asking. Do you mean you think some people might say ***hain't*** with the sense of ***isn't/aren't***? Bear in mind *ain't* also stands for *am not*, as would be the case in your first example, so that might be confusing the issue.

Comment: @Fumble Well, I believe it is local to the southern US, so I would be surprised if you'd heard it. And yes, whether some people say *hain't* meaning *isn't*.

Comment: If they *do*, it is effectively the same as Mockney overcorrection. [Hindeed! Ain't it so?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hindeed%22+%22ain+t%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Though 'estuarians' and 'crackers' have a common language _somewhere_ in their past, the latter don't historically have h-dropping and so the phenomenon (if there is one in the south) is very unlikely to be overcorrection like the Cockneys closer to you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: _Some_ (not much, just some) Southern AmE has th-fronting (but only intermedially) e.g. brother -> bruvver. Which specific locality I can't name.

Comment: @Mitch: *Bruvver* is common in Cockney speech too, but I must admit I've never come across the corresponding overcorrection that might cause someone to say, for example, *luth* instead of *love*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may not be confirmation, but Mark Twain, who has [this](http://www.gradesaver.com/the-adventures-of-huckleberry-finn/e-text/section1/) to say about his dialectical decisions in *The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*, uses both words following the distinctions you have made.

He uses ain't solely to me "am not", "are not", or "is not", as in:

> "'Stuff! stealing cattle and such things ain't robbery; it's burglary,' says Tom Sawyer.  'We ain't burglars.  That ain't no sort of style.  We are highwaymen.'"

By comparison, he uses *hain't* to mean "has not" or "have not", as in:

> "'I hain't ever done you no harm.  You know that.  So, then, what you want to come back and ha'nt me for?'
>   I says:
>   'I hain't come back—I hain't been gone.'"

Wiktionary [claims](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hain%27t) that in certain dialects, *hain't* and *ain't* are synonymous.

> *Hain’t* originally derived from *han’t*, and meant "has not" and "have not". In certain h-adding modern dialects, *hain’t* is synonymous with, and a replacement for, *ain’t* in all its uses.

However, if you're writing or speaking in a dialect that uses these variations and you plan on employing both, interchanging them may cause confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the references and the excellent answer. I am suspicious of the Wiktionary entry though. It lists *hain't* as archaic, which I find unlikely. (And I am planning to write in this dialect. You're very astute.)

Comment: @KitFox: Wiktionary also explains that "hain't" derived from "han't" which, apparently, is still used in substandard Modern English. I disagree with that, too. I have never heard *han't* in any dialect, although I have heard *hain't*.

Comment: @tylerharms  I very frequently hear, and generally say myself, [hæənt] for both *hasn’t* and *hadn’t*. I don't recall seeing it written, however, in any text since the early 19th century. I don't think it's ‘substandard’ at all, merely normal elision.

Answer (score 2):

*Hain’t* is attested by over 30 citations in the Oxford English Dictionary. A typical example from 1878 is ‘Nobody can say she hain't been a good yoke-fellow; she's kept up her end’, while another from 1898 is ‘I hain't ben runnin' the Eagle tavern fer quite a consid'able while.’

I would imagine that this pronunciation of ‘ain’t’ arose from uncertainty over whether or not to pronounce /h/ at the beginning of words that begin with a vowel. Those two citations suggest a London dialect, but I have never heard it myself anywhere in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

From 10 years old to 18, I heard and eventually used hain't and ain't interchangeably in informal speech. I remember in the early 1970s one of my classmates found ain't in a dictionary.  Students were saying "Ain't is a word, but hain't ain't." The community speaks Core Sound Brogue, like the nearby Ocracoke Island and Hatteras Island accents -- all in North Carolina. Core Sound Brogue is not an h-adding dialect. As an adult I sometimes use hain't for emphasis relative to ain't; I don't know if others do. Southerners around me in and north of Atlanta Georgia either understand my usage or do not notice it.